# How to find the amount to added every month or year to get the required amount after certain years?

Tags: computer-science, finance

I want to do a Java application for which after giving the current savings, and the rate of interest and  and required amount after specified  no of years, it has to show how much a person has to earn a month or year to achieve his target.
I'm aware of the formula $$\text{present value}={\text{future value} \over (1+\text{interest rate})^{\text{no. of years}}}$$
Now after 
getting present value, should I divide present value by no. of months in those years, to get the amount he has to invest per month ?

Comment: The OP's formula does **not** apply to a series of payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you need is the future value of an ordinary annuity:

$$F=R \times \frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}$$where F is the value at the time of the last payment, R is the size of the regular payment, i is the interest rate per payment period and n is the number of regular payments.

The compounding period of the interest rate must match the payment period...

REVISED ANSWER:
Assume you **start** with B dollars, and wish to accumulate **a total of** C dollars after n years, making annual deposits of R dollars, and earning an annual rate of i per year as you go.

The original amount will grow, all by itself, to $B'$ at the end of the payments:

$$B'=B \times (1+i)^n $$Assuming that this is less than your target of C dollars, the regular payments must make up the difference of $C-B'$.  Re-arranging the formula for the future value of an annuity: $$R=(C-B') \times \frac{i}{(1+i)^n-1}$$

Comment: but i need only formula with respect to future value , present value @User58220

Comment: There is no such formula.  You cannot deal with amounts at different times by simply adding them.  The first payment will earn interest for n periods, the second for (n-1) periods and so on...

Comment: so you mean to say i need to find R ? can you provide me a link regarding this subject @User58220

Comment: Yes, use this formula to find R.   Check Wikpedia for Annuity_(finance_theory)

Comment: but how about the initial amount i am having ?you did not mention in the formula @User58220

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [*geometric mean*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Proportional_growth). It can be used to find average growth rates. From the average rate and the given amount you can easily derive the average increase per time period.

**EDIT**
Maybe you're looking for this:

$$(1+\text{interest rate})^{\text{no. of years}}=\frac{\text{future value}} {\text{present value}}$$

$$\text{interest rate}=\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}\text{no. of years}]{\frac{\text{future value}} {\text{present value}}} - 1$$